# How to see which clients are requesting in my apache?

Tags: apache

I am using apache2 in my Ubuntu 13.10 as a server. Now How can I see the IP of the clients ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the default configuration of Ubuntu 13.10:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

You can also do a "live view" that updates whenever someone accesses your page:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Comment: How do I know which files were requested?

Comment: Each line contains the following information: IP address of the client, time and date, request (e.g. GET or POST), URL, referrer, response code (e.g. 404) and the user agent.

Comment: -_- .. Someone wrote nasty messages. I don't know how,, I didn't give my ip to anyone else.. Thanks BTW, I will accept your ans.

Comment: If the server is connected to the Internet: There are bots that will visit most IP addresses and check for vulnerable software. Additionally, there are spam bots that check for HTML forms and submit spam to them. The tail command above only shows the last entries. If you want to see all of them, use "less" instead of "tail".

Comment: Can You tell me if this request is something evil ? `GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.` and `"GET /MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 481 "-" "ZmEu"
`

Comment: It means that someone tried to find a vulnerable software, but wasn't successful as there is a 404 response.

Comment: Owh man... I had a form and I thought no one's gonna look at that -_- .. I didn't knew about random bots..I am new at this thank you very much